# What am I doing wrong here? No matter what I do, the function askSubscriptionQuestions does not store the values of the 4 floats

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So this is a program that calculates the sum of all monthly subscriptions. But the problem is that the values of netflixBill, disneyBill etc. are 0 at the function call so the sum is only the struct elements. I have tried everything I know but I don't understand why it does not work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Etlv.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Subscription {
  char name[100];
  float price;
};



int check_login(char *, char *);
void askSubscriptionQuestions(bool *, bool *, bool *, bool *);
struct Subscription ask_subscription();
float total_price(struct Subscription subscriptions[], int num_subscriptions, float netflixBill, float disneyBill, float hboBill, float spotifyBill);


struct Subscription ask_subscription(void) {
  struct Subscription subscription;
  printf("What is the name of the subscription? ");
  scanf("%s", subscription.name);
  printf("How much do you pay every month for it? ");
  scanf("%f", &subscription.price);
  return subscription;
}

int main()
{
  float netflixBill = 0.0f, disneyBill = 0.0f, hboBill = 0.0f, spotifyBill = 0.0f;
  char id[20];
  char password[20];
  bool hasPassed;
  bool hasNetflix;
  bool hasDisneyPlus;
  bool hasHBO;
  bool hasSpotify;
  char response;
  struct Subscription subscriptions[100];
  int num_subscriptions = 0;
  while (1) {
    printf("Enter your ID: ");
    scanf("%s", id);

    printf("Enter your password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    if (check_login(id, password)) {
      printf("Access granted.\n");
      hasPassed = true;
      break;
    } else {
      hasPassed = false;
      printf("Access denied.\n");
    }
  }



  printf("Do you have any monthly subscriptions? (y/n) ");
  char c;

  while (c != 'y' && c != 'Y' && c != 'n' && c != 'N') {
    scanf("%s", &c);
    if (c != 'y' && c != 'Y' && c != 'n' && c != 'N'){
      printf("Invalid input. Please enter 'y' or 'n': ");
    }
  }
printf("%f %f %f %f", netflixBill, disneyBill, hboBill, spotifyBill);
  if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y') {
    askSubscriptionQuestions(&hasNetflix, &hasDisneyPlus, &hasHBO, &hasSpotify);
  } else if (c == 'n' || c == 'N') {
    printf("OK, thank you for your answer.\n");
  }printf("%f %f %f %f", netflixBill, disneyBill, hboBill, spotifyBill);

  printf("Do you have any other monthly subscriptions (Y/N)? ex: YT Premium, iCloud, etc.\n");
  scanf("%s", &response);


  while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y') {
    subscriptions[num_subscriptions] = ask_subscription();
    num_subscriptions++;

    printf("Do you have any other monthly subscriptions (Y/N)? ");
    scanf("%s", &response);
  }

  if (num_subscriptions > 0) {
    printf("Your subscriptions are:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_subscriptions; i++) {
      printf("- %s: $%.2f\n", subscriptions[i].name, subscriptions[i].price);
    }
  } else {
    printf("You do not have any other monthly subscriptions.\n");
  }

  float total = total_price(subscriptions, num_subscriptions, netflixBill, disneyBill, hboBill, spotifyBill);
    printf("The total cost of all your subscriptions is $%.2f\n", total);
  return 0;
}

int check_login(char *id, char *password) {
  if (strcmp(id, "admin") == 0 && strcmp(password, "pass123") == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

void askSubscriptionQuestions(bool *hasNetflix, bool *hasDisneyPlus, bool *hasHBO, bool *hasSpotify) {
  char c;
  int netflixPlan, spotifyPlan;
  float netflixBill = 0.0f, disneyBill = 0.0f, hboBill = 0.0f, spotifyBill = 0.0f;
  printf("Do you have a subscription to Netflix? (y/n) ");
  scanf("%s", &c);
  if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y') {
    *hasNetflix = true;
    printf("Which monthly plan do you have? Here is a list: \n");
    printf("\t 1 for Minimum = 7.99$/month\n");
    printf("\t 2 for Standard = 9.99$/month\n");
    printf("\t 3 for Premium = 11.99/month\n");
    scanf("%d", &netflixPlan);
    if(netflixPlan == 1){
        netflixBill = 7.99;
    }
        else if(netflixPlan == 2){
            netflixBill = 9.99;
        }
            else
                netflixBill = 11.99;
        } else {
    *hasNetflix = false;
    printf("You don't have a Netflix subscription. \n");
  }

  printf("Do you have a subscription to Disney+? (y/n)\n ");
  scanf("%s", &c);
  if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y') {
    *hasDisneyPlus = true;
    disneyBill = 5.99;
    printf("The subscription for Disney+ is 5.99$/month.\n");
  } else {
    *hasDisneyPlus = false;
    printf("You don't have a Disney+ subscription. \n");
  }

  printf("Do you have a subscription to HBO? (y/n)\n ");
  scanf("%s", &c);
  if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y') {
    *hasHBO = true;
    hboBill = 4.99;
    printf("The subscription for HBO is 4.99$/month.\n");
  } else {
    *hasHBO = false;
    *hasHBO = false;
    printf("You don't have a HBO subscription. \n");
  }

  printf("Do you have a subscription to Spotify? (y/n) ");
  scanf("%s", &c);
  if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y') {
    *hasSpotify = true;
    printf("Which monthly plan do you have? Here is a list: \n");
    printf("\t 1 for Premium = 4.99$/month\n");
    printf("\t 2 for Premium for students = 2.49$/month\n");
    scanf("%d", &spotifyPlan);
    if(spotifyPlan == 1)
        spotifyBill = 4.99;
        else
            spotifyBill = 2.49;
  } else {
     printf("You don't have a Spotify subscription. \n");
    *hasSpotify = false;
  }
}

float total_price(struct Subscription subscriptions[], int num_subscriptions, float netflixBill, float disneyBill, float hboBill, float spotifyBill) {
  float total = netflixBill + disneyBill + hboBill + spotifyBill;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_subscriptions; i++) {
    total += subscriptions[i].price;
  }
  return total;
}
```

i've tried using pointers(idk if i did it right). tried using chatgpt but it does not know what the problem is either.

Comment: The variable c is uninitialized. So the following while loop invokes undefined behavior   char c;

  while (c != 'y' && c != 'Y' && c != 'n' && c != 'N') {

Comment: And this call of scanf scanf("%s", &c); also invokes undefined behavior because there is used the conversion specifier s with a scalar  object of the type char.

Comment: the variable c is initialized both in the function and the main. also i switched to %c but the program still does now work as intended

Comment: Not, you're using `c` uninitialized in this line `while (c != 'y' && c != 'Y' && c != 'n' && c != 'N')`

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't get it. I don't get any compiler errors so there is no way im using it uninitialized. but still that does not matter cause the values for netflixBill and the other 3 are still 0 at the function call.

Comment: You are not guaranteed to get a compiler error about an uninitialized variable.

Comment: It's considered good practice in many circles to *always* initialize all variables, no matter what, whether you think you need to or not.  It's likely to save you some time.  (With that said, though, it's possible there are other problems, too.)

Comment: @Robert Pal And these variables float netflixBill = 0.0f, disneyBill = 0.0f, hboBill = 0.0f, spotifyBill = 0.0f; are not used in main except they are outputted without changing them.

Comment: @SteveSummit can you help me understand where I did not initialize "c"? i cannot seem to find it.

Comment: In your code as posted there are three adjacent lines `printf("Do you have any monthly subscriptions? (y/n) ");
  char c;

  while (c != 'y' && c != 'Y' && c != 'n' && c != 'N')`.  That `char c;` in the middle there is uninitialized.

Comment: @RobertPal I showed that in my first comment. The variable is declared without an initializer.

Comment: ok, I got that, i initialized it now with '\0'. But that was not really my problem. those 4 variables are still 0. even tho they should be close to hardcoded in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related with the **scope of the variables**.

Essentially what is happening is that you are using **local variables** for assigning the values that you want inside the function *askSubscriptionQuestions*, but when you terminate this function, all the local variables are lost. Don't be confused because you named them the same way as the variables declared in the main. That doesn't matter. What matter is the scope of the variables.

Once you have declared your *netflixBill* variable in the main, you need to pass it by-reference, that means, passing the address of the variable instead of the value. You do this using "&". That way, if you properly modify value to which this address points to inside the function, when it finishes you won't loose the value of your variable.

You need to do several changes:

- Re-write your function so the header includes these variables (to define the arguments as addresses):

  void askSubscriptionQuestions(..., *netflixBill, *disneyBill, *hboBill, *spotifyBill)
- Call your function as (to send the address instead of the value):

  askSubscriptionQuestions(..., &netflixBill, &disneyBill, &hboBill, &spotifyBill)
- Inside your function, every time you want to change the value of these variables, you need to call the "value" that the address is pointing to. So, the change would be to add always a "*" before each time you call these variables **inside** this function. For example:

  *netflixBill = 7.99;
- Remove the local declaration that you are doing of the *netflixBill* variable and similar inside your function.

I highly recommend you study and understand the concept of passing variables by-reference and by-value to the functions, it is essential coding in C.

Answer (score 1):

### Uninitialised Variable:

```
char c;
while (c != 'y' && c != 'Y' && c != 'n' && c != 'N')
```

This loop invokes undefined behaviour as `c` was never initialised.

### Incorrect format specifier:

```
scanf("%s", &c);
```

The call to `scanf` also invokes Undefined Behaviour, as `c` has been declared as a `char`, and the `%s` format specifier is for strings.

I counted `7` other instances where you made the same mistake.

---

Once the abstract state machine reaches an undefined state, no further assumption about the continuation of the execution of the program can be made.

---

### Variable scope:

The variables defined in `main` are local to `main` only. You declared another instance of `spotifyBill ...` in `askSubcriptionQuestions`, these variables are local to `askSubcriptionQuestions` only. They're not visible in `main`, and the variables declared in `main` aren't visible in other functions.

- Identifiers only have visibility inside their scope, starting at their declarations.
- Objects have a lifetime outside of which they can't be accessed.
- Referring to an object outside of its lifetime has Undefined Behaviour.
- Unless they are `VLA` or temporary objects, automatic variables have a lifetime corresponding to the execution of their block of defination

If you want to work with the same variables declared in main, you'd have to pass them `by reference` to other functions. That way, the changes made to those variables will be permanent.

Comment: I fixed everything you said, but the problem still appears. netflixBill + disneyBill + hboBill + spotifyBill, dont maintain their values from the askSubscriptionQuestions function. their values go back to 0.0 and remain unchanged for the rest of the program. but i want them to maintain their values so they can be used in the total_price function, where they are going to be summed up. can you please help me with this it's driving me crazy :(